# Unit test a method with argument of type HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, http, model-view-controller, request

As the title describes my method has an argument of type HttpServletRequest and I want to do unit testing, which means that I have to create a request bind a parameter to it and pass it to the method I want to test. However, I am not able to create an instance of type HttpServletRequest and set a parameter to it in my java code. 
This works fine when the request is passed by the web server but it seems problematic when I want to create an HTTP servlet request in my java code with a test parameter in it. Is there a workaround for this issue ? How would someone unit test a method that accepts HTTPServletRequests ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocking.  Spring has a MockHttpServletRequest or you can simply use something like Mockito. Then you set the return values for the methods you are interested in and ignore everything else.

Comment: I would use a fake rather than a mock... something which just lets me *set* various things about the request, and then let the getters return them. That's likely to be considerably simpler than using a true mock, even in a framework which allows mocks to act more like stubs.